# Substring/toString/IndexOf Function not working past a certain value

Tags: java

I have a function:

```
ItemValue[i] = substring(toString(obj),0,toString(obj).indexOf(".") + 4);
```

where obj is a number. The function works for 9,999,999.99999 -> 9999999.999 but values such as 99,999,999.99999 gets converted to 9.999.

Is it a data type issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Java *or* Javascript? Choose one.

Comment: For one, this isn't valid JavaScript. So I'd guess it's Java.

Comment: as far as I know, neither `substring` nor `toString` is a predefined global function in either java or javascript.

Comment: @JanDvorak: `toString` and `substring`. He could of course have defined functions with those names.

Comment: thus, closevoting as unclear

Comment: @JohnJones we still don't know these functions you've defined,

Comment: Just print your parameters and you'll understand what your functions are doing.

Comment: sorry let me define my functions!

Comment: SUBSTRING (dynamic.array, start, length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the double values you are using. The value `99999999.99999` will be translated to `9.999999999999E7` by `toString()` so the results you are getting. In order to strip the digits after decimal you can use `DecimalFormat` class:

```
    DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat();
    f.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
    f.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
```